# Append string to every url on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my website in English but want to show it in Spanish when page loads. So, I got a script from Google Translate that I put in my header file but I need to append some `#googtrans(en|fr)` at the end of every URL. What I've done so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').each(function () {
    this.href += '#googtrans(en|es)';
  })
});
```

But a problem with this code is, it is blocking my popups and bootstrap dropdowns.
Is there any simple way to put that trailing string to every URL on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out links that have attributes or classes you don't want the hash applied to:

For example:

```
$('a').not('[data-toggle], [href^="#"]').prop('hash','#googtrans(en|es)');
```

If selectors in `not()` aren't enough you can use the more robust `filter()` method

A more ideal approach would be being able to have classes on your `<a>` to represent the ones you do want modified.

```
<a class="translate">
$('a.translate').prop('hash','#googtrans(en|es)');
```

OR

```
<div class="translate">
   <a>
</div>
$('.translate a').prop('hash','#googtrans(en|es)');
```

Note that using the hash property achieves the same as concatenating `href`

Without seeing more of your html it is hard to provide a lot more help

Comment: But how to automatically append this hash if visitor writes the url in address bar without hash.

Comment: @JunaidKhawaja that's a completely separate issue. Would store in cookie or localStorage and check value on page load and update hash accordingly. Is probably part of the translate script api also to be able to trigegr changes

Comment: I've figured out that issue with location.hash.

Comment: Thanks for your help, :)

Answer (score 0):

Now you replace with this code all `<a>` tags.

Best way - it's taking Google Translator block links on other div, like this:

```
<div id="gtr">
  ...
</div>
```

And Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#gtr a').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+'#googtrans(en|es)');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
this.href += “#googtrans(en|es)”;
```

Try this:

```
$(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "#googtrans(en|es)");
```